# JStree: Track drag & drop in a tree

Tags: jstree

I'm (trying to) using JStree for a categorie/subcategorie tree.
It took quite some time, but I managed to create a tree with JSON data I retrieve from a database (using PHP for quering and building the JSON objects).

Now I would like to be able to keep track of drag & drop actions.
I.e.: subcategorie x from maincategory a is dragged to maincategorie b.
I need to record this to change the database after the action.
I figured I would need either the 'check_move' or 'drop_finish' functions.
drop-finish doesn't work at all, the event is not triggered. This seems to be because my nodes do not have the jstree-drop class, but I can't seem to get the class correctly inserted: it won't work.

The check_move function will keep triggering when passing other subcategories and therefor creates an load of unwanted data.

My (test) JSON data:

```
[
{
    "metadata": {
        "id": "1"
    },
    "data": "Geluid",
    "children": [
        {
            "data": "Speakers",
            "attr": {
                "href": ""
            },
            "metadata": {
                "id": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "Versterkers",
            "attr": {
                "href": ""
            },
            "metadata": {
                "id": "3"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "metadata": {
        "id": "2"
    },
    "data": "Licht",
    "children": [
        {
            "data": "Parren",
            "attr": {
                "href": ""
            },
            "metadata": {
                "id": "2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

My JStree code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#Create").click(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree("create");
    });     
  $("#Rename").click(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree("rename");
  });
  $("#Remove").click(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree("remove");
    });


    $("#tree").jstree({
        "dnd" : {
          "drop_finish" : function (data) {
         alert ("Drag OK");
          //alert("Dragged: " + data.o.attr('id') + " to " + data.r.attr('id'));         
        }
      },
      "themes" : {
            "theme" : "classic",
            "dots" : true,
            "icons" : false
        },
      "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "get_category_tree.php"
            }
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "checkbox", "dnd" ]
    })
    .bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
      var req = new ZaxasRequest();
      req.getContent("category_content.php?id=" + data.rslt.obj.data('id') +"", "category_content");
    })
});
```

Basically, I would like to get the ID's. Don't bother about the fact the maincategory and subcategory id might be the same, I'll fix that problem later on ;)
Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: The answer to a similar question is found here.

[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110708/bindmove-node-jstree-data-rslt-obj-undefined-how-to-get-node-data

Comment: [Since I don't have enough rep to post a comment, I'm posting this as a new answer.] The CRRM plugin doesn't exist in the current version of jstree. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011542/1676689) to a related question to find a working example of drag and drop in version 3.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the move event and use CRRM plugin ...
I'll post some code example later.. 
[JSTree CRRM](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/crrm)

Comment: As of 2016, the link you provided does not have CRRM plugin